# Magento2: How to set minimum order amount for specific group

Tags: magento2

I have created some customers group.

How to set minimum order amount only for specific group?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the third-party modules to set a minimum order amount for a specific group.

https://marketplace.magento.com/meetanshi-magento2-minimum-order-amount-for-customer-group.html

https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-minimum-order-amount-for-customer-group-extension.html

https://shreejiinfosys.co.in/minimum-order-amount-by-customer-group-magento-2.html

https://azaleasoft.com/m2-minimum-order-amount-for-customer-group.html

**Or**

Another option is to Customize this functionality.

Comment: Is any available free solution?